# How to fix 'Image Source Url is missing' issue when using Django CkEditor

Tags: django, python-3.x, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I installed djnago-ckeditor and followed the installation guide. Using `RichTextUpload()` for my models which are imported from `ckeditor_uploader`. When I try to upload an image it is saying that

> Image Source Url is missing'.

I'm using python, django latest versions

## basesettings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
......
'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_ROOT, 'ckeditor_media')
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'height': 300,
        'width': '100%',
    },
}
```

## urls.py

```
path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

## models.py

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
...Model
about = RichTextUploadingField()
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with an easy Non-programming solution!
uploading a picture actually has 2 steps but maybe you did not pay attention to it just like me!
just click on the "send it to the server" after you upload it! I  did this in admin. I hope that's what you're looking for.

[image: uploading a picture with ckeditor]
uploading a picture with ckeditor